# The report execution XXXXXXXXXX has expired or cannot be found. [rsExecutionNotFound]

Tags: reporting-services, session-state

In our ASP.Net application, we are using SSRS. As long as sessionstate is configured to run as InProc, everything works fine.

Recently, we change the session state management to Redis. With this configuration, sometime we are getting the following exception,

The report execution XXXXXXXXXX has expired or cannot be found. [rsExecutionNotFound]

Comment: Have you googled the error before coming here?

Comment: Hi Hari, Any success on this. Even i am getting the same error. Due to which session gets write lock.